# How to configure DTLS echo server and client code?

Tags: openssl, sctp, dtls

I found the web archives of DTLS SCTP sample code.
http://web.archive.org/web/20150617012520/http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html

I want to run the DTLS echo server and client. However, I`m unable to compile.
Here is error contents:

```
$gcc dtls-over-sctp-echo.c -o main -I /usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -Wall
         dtls-over-sctp-echo.c: In function ‘connection_handle’:
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:219:32: error: storage size of ‘rinfo’ isn’t known
          struct bio_dgram_sctp_rcvinfo rinfo;
                                        ^
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:228:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BIO_new_dgram_sctp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          bio = BIO_new_dgram_sctp(pinfo->fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
                ^
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:228:6: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
          bio = BIO_new_dgram_sctp(pinfo->fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
              ^
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:232:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BIO_dgram_sctp_notification_cb’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
           BIO_dgram_sctp_notification_cb(bio, &handle_notifications, (void*) ssl);
           ^
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:291:21: error: ‘BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SCTP_GET_RCVINFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
               BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SCTP_GET_RCVINFO, sizeof(struct bio_dgram_sctp_rcvinfo), &rinf
                             ^
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:291:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
        dtls-over-sctp-echo.c:291:61: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct bio_dgram_sctp_rcvinfo’
               BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SCTP_GET_RCVINFO, sizeof(struct bio_dgram_sctp_rcvinfo), &rinf
```

Thanks!.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a `#include <openssl/bio.h>`.  Alternatively, is the OpenSSL package you have installed from a significantly different version than the sample code expects?

Comment: 1. refer to [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068706/dtls-over-sctp-using-openssl#new-answer -- sysctl -w net.sctp.auth_enable=1

Answer (score 0):

1. try build openssl source code again using:

   `./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib shared sctp`
2. install openssl
3. rebuild dtls_sctp_echo.c with new openssl library

Comment: 1. and then refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068706/dtls-over-sctp-using-openssl#new-answer                 sysctl -w net.sctp.auth_enable = 1